# Using drupal behaviors for a Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript

I created a custom front page using page--front.tpl.php, and I added a Bootstrap carousel on it which works fine, but the javascript I have (carou.js which is in mysubtheme'/js/carou.js') is not called. This is the Drupal behavior code.

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.carou = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            pause: false,
            interval: 3000,
        });
    }
}       
})(jQuery);
```

I added it using the following code in the template.php file.

```
function bootstrap_subtheme_preprocess_page($vars) {
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
     drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'bootstrap_subtheme') . "/css/frontpage.css");
   //adding carou.js to front page
     drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'bootstrap_subtheme') . '/js/carou.js', 'file');
   }
}
```

I want to control the carousel options of `pause: false` `interval:3000` but I was not able to do so. This makes me think the JavaScript code is not being called, and I don't know what is not right in the code. I am not also very well versed with Drupal behaviors.

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Does ID myCarousel exist? If you put a console.log() or an alert() in the attach method, is that called?

Comment: yeah. it does exist. its the ID for the working carousel (#myCarousel) i have created.

Comment: And what did debugging with a console.log() reveal?

Comment: i didn't debug it but what i was meaning is the ID is for the carousel i created

Comment: My subtheme name is bootstrap_subtheme as shown in the code snippet i posted above.

Comment: Is the JS file referenced in the HTML if you turn off aggregation in the Drupal performance settings?

Comment: Yes. the JS file is referenced. i appreciate your time you are dedicating.

Comment: The next natural thing is to put a console.log in the attach method to be sure that is called. Also make sure "carou" property in Drupal.behaviors.carou is unique on this system.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it. I modified the code this way

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'bootstrap_subtheme') . '/js/carou.js', array( 
                                                                                      'type' => 'file', 
                                                                                      'group' => JS_LIBRARY, 
                                                                                      'weight' => -1));
```

I added group and weight to it then then drupal.behaviors code had some few errors in the structure. The last line was`})(jQuery);`
But i fixed it to `}(jQuery));`